# Adjust Bootstrap accordion button height based on text

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

How do you adjust the button height of this accordion from bootstrap so that the text wraps round in the same way it does for the card-body.

I've tried playing about with the CSS but I haven't had any success yet, maybe someone here knows?

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry if I've done something incorrect with regards to the formatting it's my first time posting here.

https://jsfiddle.net/2qonLz4b/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below CSS code in your custom css file:

```
.accordion .btn {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: If you satisfied with the answer. please accept and upvote.

Comment: I will do just need to wait 4 mins haha